"UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 …" works with Access but not with UCanAccess
My database, which lives in MS Access and is accessible to DBeaver by the UCanAccess driver, contains two tables, which I'll call Table1 and Table2. I want to update Table1 based on entries in Table2 and I have tried many variations on what I have found in StackOverflow, including:
UPDATE [Table1]
SET [Table1].[Column1] = [Table2].[ThingsToUpdateTo]
WHERE [Table1].[Column2] = [Table2].[Reference];

I get an error:

SQL Error [42501]: UCAExc:::5.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: [Table2].[ThingsToUpdateTo]

I've tried using a SELECT statement in the SET line only, which gives the same error but on the next line, and I've tried using SELECT statements in both SET and WHERE. I have also tried putting [Table1] and [Table2] in the UPDATE line.
I feel like there must be something very simple that I'm missing that's causing my statement not to be able to reference Table2 to update Table1. Thanks in advance!
I've tried using a SELECT statement in the SET line only, which gives the same error but on the next line, and I've tried using SELECT statements in both SET and WHERE. I have also tried putting [Table1] and [Table2] in the UPDATE line. These resolve the "user lacks privilege" type error and throws a "cardinality violation" error.
Tried
UPDATE Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Column2 = Table2.Reference 
SET Table1.Column1 = Table2.ThingsToUpdateTo;

This did attempt to update records, but I get another error:

Unexpected token: INNER required: SET

I also tried:
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = Table2.ThingSToUpdateTo
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON t1.Column2 = t2.Reference;

Also attempted to update records, and got error:

user lacks privilege or object not found: t2.ThingsToUpdateTo

I've also tried running all of these queries in Access instead of in DBeaver, to no avail.

Your 2nd example is correct & should run in Access itself just fine, what happens when to do so?

Note that UCanAccess uses a different database engine than the Access Database Engine. Example 2 should work in Access, but I'm not sure about executing it through UCanAccess.

Why duplicate data between tables?

The Second example did run in Access, thank you.

I'm using Table2 to help me migrate data into Table1, Table2 is only a temporary table to help me merge data from multiple sources, currently being stored inefficiently.

This will be a periodic process, not just a one-timer?

Mainly there are just too many records for this to be practical to do manually, and I have wanted to use this solution for more than 3 situations, so I felt it was worth writing.

As Erik mentions in a comment to the question, UCanAccess does not use the Access Database Engine. It uses HSQLDB to process SQL commands and Jackcess to write changes back to the Access database file.
So, instead of using Access' non-standard UPDATE … JOIN syntax, we need to use the  ANSI standard syntax
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET Column1 = (
    SELECT ThingsToUpdateTo FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Column2 = t2.Reference
    )

Note that the syntax for updating multiple columns at the same time is
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET (Column1, Comments) = (
    SELECT ThingsToUpdateTo, Notes FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Column2 = t2.Reference
    )

